# QGIS Model Designer: 'Algorithm is not available' and 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'displayName'

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am building a model to automate a process of generating points at street intersections. When I run the model, there is no output. Checking the error logs, I see this:

```
2022-04-26T10:55:36     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerGraphicItem.py", line 177, in editComponent
          self.edit()
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerGraphicItem.py", line 151, in edit
          self.component().configuration())
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerParametersDialog.py", line 77, in __init__
          self.setWindowTitle(self._alg.displayName())
         AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'displayName'
```

This is the model I am creating. There is a red error icon in the top left of the model designer, which when clicked, gives me the aforementioned error.

Whenever I make changes to the model such as converting a model output to algorithm output, I get this error.

[image: model screenshot]

When I run the model by clicking the green arrow, I get an error warning saying an algorithm is not available. But all the algorithms I use in the model are from the algorithm sidebar.
[image: error warning before running model]

I am not developing a Python script, I am just using the model designer in QGIS. What do I have to do to make the model work?

EDIT: I have created a new model. I find that when I copy and paste an algorithm, I get this error.
The only time I can get the model to work is when I create model output for each step, but that is not what I want; I just want model output for the end step.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but my model is a simpler one, baseline a series of linear actions. So I simply cut it down to each step and run it to find out the problem. I suspect one of your algorithm output is not valid, may be the 'mean coordinate' action. I suggest you build and run it step by step to find out the issue.